# What is the best way to list code snippets in a undergraduate thesis?

Tags: computer-science

For some reason I am having difficulty figuring out a good way to list code snippets in my undergrad thesis. My project is on development of some software and I've thought about doing this.

`Algorithm 1 - description of what the code does`

But then I realize algorithm really isn't the right word. I've thought about using the word `procedure` but then again I don't know if declared classes count as procedures. Can someone offer some advice?

Comment: What's wrong with "snippet"?

Comment: @AzorAhai Thought there was a better word for it, but appearently not. Thank you.

Comment: How about code extract?

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Answer (score 2):

*Listing* is another word that gets used sometimes. It sounds a bit unnatural to me though; maybe it is in wide use just because it is used in a certain Latex package.

Comment: Maybe that is why 'listing' remains widely used now, but the word was definitively widespread already before the birth of TeX, thus predating the package by at least a decade. And the practice itself of printing lists of instructions goes back at least to 1970, but I'm not sure when it acquired its name.